# Nodejs: Child_process.exec is not executing any commands also not getting any issue

Tags: node.js, cmd, child-process

I am trying to open file via node application for which I have used below code.

```
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const { exec } = require('child_process');

//var exec = require( 'child_process' ).exec;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  // console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  
  
    try{
        
        console.log("yet to exec");
    exec( "C:/Windows/System32/RunDLL32.exe SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL ?0x8100? 'C:\Users\USER_NAME\.TEMPFOLDER\ID\0\0-999\373\S\v4\SAMPLE.doc'",
    {}, function(error){
        console.log("Error: "+error);
    });
    }catch(ex){
    console.log("ex: "+ex);
    }
})
```

I am using exec method in child_proccess library to do this task. But the file is not opening also, I am not getting any error both in error callback also, no exception occurs. I have also checked the event viewer of the system but found no issue log regarding this. But, I can able to open the file using the same command via command prompt. It would be helpful if anybody help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even with the child_process's methods you could use any program(binary), as you are using Nodejs which is multiplatform, i would recommand you to stick with it.

Let me give you an exemple with Nodejs and 'exec'.
The first argument is the binary(or the access to the binary) of the program you want to use, so for Node it will be `node` (but we will use the direct path to it `process.execPath`).

The second argument for Nodejs is `-e`(execute) or `-p`(print), that is the basic of Nodejs when you use the Node cli.

The third argument will be the Node command, as you run the Node binary you have direct access to all Node's core-modules, so to read a file we use the `fs` module.

The `exec` function return a Callback spliting out an `err`, `stdout` and `stderr`.

See the command

```
   // __filename point to the current file, build your path and replace it with
    exec(
       `${process.execPath} -p "fs.readFileSync('${__filename}')"`, 
        (err, stdout, stderr) => {
           if(err) console.log(err)
           // the stdout is a buffer(binary format), toString() to encode utf8
           console.log(stdout.toString())
        }
    )
```